# SQL compare and match columns from 2 tables

Tags: sql, compare

I am attempting to join two tables by comparing and matching values in separate columns. Please bear with me:

```
Table 1 
==========
Name
IP address 

Table 2 
==========
IP address
Rating
```

I need to write a query that groups all the IP addresses that correspond to a certain group in the Name column from Table 1and match them with a rating from Table 2.

Can someone point me in the direction of the type of queries I should be looking at?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should add that tag. You'll probably get more help if you show what you've tried so far; this is basic SQL, and you should show some effort toward solving it yourself. A hint? `JOIN` should get you started.

Comment: I was going to write a comment, but Ken covered everything I was going to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without completely spelling it out for all the reasons that @KenWhite mentioned in his comment...

When you relate data from two different tables (in your case trying to find common IP addresses), you'll usually want to use some form of a `JOIN`.  There are many different kinds of these.  [Here](http://tsqlexamples.com/joins.aspx) is a good reference, but there are many other good references if you spend some time searching for them.

The decision of which kind of `JOIN` to use will come down to whether or not you want to display IP Addresses which have no corresponding rating.

Moving on - you mentioned that you want to only show ratings for IP addresses that correspond to a certain Name group.  For that, you'll need to use a `WHERE` clause in your query.  This is pretty straight forward - for reference, you can visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188047.aspx).

I think with these references and a bit of research / effort on your part, writing the query you describe shouldn't be an issue.